# Joint probability in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I have a finite sequence of discrete values X = {x1, x2, x3...xn} and I want to compute the joint probability of each pair of elements in the sequence. i.e, P(x1, x2), P(x2, x3) etc. How should I implement this in R? I don't have much experience doing such analysis in R. Are there any built in functions to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume independence then the joint probability is trivial trivial you have $P(a,b)=P(a)P(b)$. Otherwise you need to estimate the probabilities of each pair individually.

To do so, you can get a list of pairs of the same form using `mapply`, then you can estimate the probabilities using the relative abundance of each pair. Here I'm just illustrating a point, I haven't run this code.

```
L <- length(X)
X.pairs <- mapply(
    function(x1, x2) paste(x1, x2, sep=','),
    X[1:(L-1)],
    X[2:L]
)
table(X.pairs)
```

Edit: this is for discrete values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
library(MASS)
den2d <- kde2d(x,y)
image(den2d)
persp(den2d,phi=30,theta=20)
```

This is described in the MASS book Section 5.6 Density Estimation, subsection Two-dimensional data. There are examples and further references. I cannot post their examples here due to copyright.

Comment: Thanks. But, Isnt this only for continuous valued data? What about discrete?

Comment: it will work fine. when you provide a finite vector of actual numbers, they are always discrete. if you want to make it less smooth then play with the kernel parameters. experts write books on density estimation, so if you read those you will know more than me.